# Reset database at the end of test

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I want to reset my test database after each test but somehow can't find a way to do it. Can delete the data added in each test but I am pretty sure this is not the correct approach. What I have as test is simply this:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Tests\Unit\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;
use Tests\Shared\Factory\UserFactory;


final class UserTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    public function testGettersReturnCorrectData(): void
    {
        self::bootKernel();

        /** @var UserRepository $repo */
        $repo = self::getContainer()->get(UserRepository::class);
        
        $user = UserFactory::createUser();
        $repo->add($user, true);
        $this->assertSame($user->getEmail(), UserFactory::EMAIL);
        $this->assertSame($user->getPassword(), UserFactory::PASSWORD);
        $this->assertSame($user->getReferralCode(), UserFactory::REFERRAL_CODE);
    }
}
```

The newly created user stays in the db. I am using MySQL test db because my production db will be MySQL and don't want to reach some corner cases because of the different dbs.
This is my env.test if needed.

```
# define your env variables for the test env here
KERNEL_CLASS='App\Kernel'
APP_SECRET='$ecretf0rt3st'
SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER=999999
PANTHER_APP_ENV=panther
PANTHER_ERROR_SCREENSHOT_DIR=./var/error-screenshots
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:toma123@127.0.0.1:3306/api?serverVersion=5.7&charset=utf8mb4"
```

Comment: you might look at [Zenstruck Foundry](https://symfony.com/bundles/ZenstruckFoundryBundle/current/index.html#database-reset) to help with that (and lots of other stuff)

Comment: @craigh What if I simply write a command that runs `doctrine:schema:drop/doctrine:schema:create`? As per my understanding this will be enough for my case. Am I right ?

Comment: If emptying the test database completely is what you mean by resetting the database (I understood resetting as getting it back to the state where it was before the test which isn't necessarily the same as empty) then the schema commands should work fine for this purpose. You can combine it with fixtures to populate the default database afterwards if needed. If you have a bigger project and lots of test cases, this approach will lead to pretty slow ploughing on the test execution part.

Comment: Use the `setUp` and `tearDown` methods to which run before and after each test. https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/fixtures.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this package https://github.com/dmaicher/doctrine-test-bundle
Disclaimer: I haven't test it myself

---

I remember done similar things using setup and teardown in PHPUnit and using transactional feature.

If I found the code or recreate it, I will let you know or update this post.

Comment: that package is always worth looking at!

Answer (score -1):

by the love of god, follow @craigh 's advice and look into foundry

https://symfony.com/bundles/ZenstruckFoundryBundle/current/index.html#database-reset

they do exactly that, and actually provide good stuff so you can build your test database inside each test case. Symfony's fixtures solution, in my subjective opinion, is worse than foundry.

Comment: Using Zenstruck Foundry will be overkill for this task. I think we can simply do DB transaction and run it at setup & teardown.